# Handover Protocol in Facebook Messenger

Tags: facebook, ibm-watson, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, watson-assistant

I have been trying to build a bot with Facebook Messenger. I want to do the handover protocol but it is not working as expected. First I can't find much documentation online on the PSID. Following this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/handover-protocol/pass-thread-control) and looking at the curl command below, I can't seem to find the PSID. Is PSID the user ID associated with a particular page and if so where can I find it manually. I have looked at Business Settings and that the "Facebook Page" and "App" must be tied to the same company before it can work and I have already done so.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "recipient":{"id":"<PSID>"},
  "target_app_id":123456789,
  "metadata":"String to pass to secondary receiver app" 
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/pass_thread_control?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>"
```

Let's say even if I can do it via curl and I want to automate this with code, my Messenger is integrated with IBM Watson Assistant, and there doesn't seem to be a way where you can do something like FacebookResponse.PSID and pass the PSID to any sort of backend code powering the Watson Assistant.

Would appreciate if anyone can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From your posting I take it that you have a Watson Assistant dialog, which you would like to connect to Facebook messenger? 
If this is the case, the Facebook skill integration will perform this task. Its also well documented on how to connect the two. You need to create a Facebook "App", along with its own Facebook page. The required settings for Facebook will be detailed on this setup page. Follow the instructions found here. 
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-deploy-facebook

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, do note that I need to use the handover protocol to connect the bot and handover the bot to a human agent. The IBM Integration does not cover this use case in the documentation. It is not just a chat with a bot on Facebook Messenger use case.

Comment: ok, I now understand your issue. However this sounds like a Facebook issue, in that they have not defined enough information for you to determine how to find the right info. You will also need to create your own Watson Assistant to Facebook orchestration layer. As what you are asking is beyond the current built-in assistant integration skill. Have you tried posing your question on Facebooks developer forum?

Comment: Ok sure I will look at asking for more help in Facebook developer forum. Thanks!

Comment: Facebook does have a way to "Pass Thread Control" from the Watson Bot (FB APP) to the page's Inbox (A human on Messenger) https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/handover-protocol/pass-thread-control. However, Watson does not implement this. I think only Watson can see the PSID, and I have not solved how to get it either.

Comment: I have not had the opportunity to play with the "Pass Thread Control" element. And I agree in the current configuration, when control is passed from FB to the Watson FB Integration layer, you would lose all sight of this type of info. Maybe worth putting in a request to the IBM Watson Assistant Offering management team, about allowing access to this information.  Otherwise you would need to implement your own FB integration layer, where you would have access to this info.